# Sitecore WFFM package installation Fails : ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance

Tags: mongodb, iis, sitecore

Hi my WFFM package installation fails due to below error

**SW Details:**

1. Sitecore Version installed is 8.2 update-4.
2. WFFM Version is (8.2 rev. 170518)
3. Sitecore IIS instance and mongo in different servers.

**Steps i have tried below**

1. Hope connectivity issue from mongo,So I tried mongo with authentication and without authentication setup. Nothing helps got the same issue only.(From mongo compass i can able to login mongo server and see the dbs)
2. Even try disabed the xdb and tracking also nothing helps.

**Error as popup below:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.   ValueFactory attempted to access
>   the Value property of this instance.   Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.   Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the
>   Value property of this instance.   Source Error:   An unhandled
>   exception was generated during the execution of the current web
>   request.  Information regarding the origin and location of the
>   exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>       [InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.]    System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +737 
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +431
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`2.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IChildSerializerConfigurable.get_ChildSerializer()
>   +15    Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(IBsonSerializer
>   serializer) +109
>
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(IBsonSerializer
>   serializer) +120
>
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(BsonMemberMap
>   memberMap) +33
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions.ConventionRunner.Apply(BsonClassMap
>   classMap) +358
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.AutoMapClass() +79
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(Type classType)
>   +435    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type
>   type, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) +249
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.CreateSerializer(Type
>   type) +174
>
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +84
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonMemberMap.GetSerializer() +373
>
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(BsonMemberMap
>   memberMap) +22
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions.ConventionRunner.Apply(BsonClassMap
>   classMap) +358
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.AutoMapClass() +79
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(Type classType)
>   +435    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type
>   type, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) +249
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.CreateSerializer(Type
>   type) +174
>
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +84
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.GetSerializer() +58 
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +737    System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +431
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`2.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.
>   IChildSerializerConfigurable.get_ChildSerializer() +15
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(IBsonSerializer
>   serializer) +109
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(IBsonSerializer
>   serializer) +120
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(BsonMemberMap
>   memberMap) +33
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions.ConventionRunner.Apply(BsonClassMap
>   classMap) +358
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.AutoMapClass() +79
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(Type classType)
>   +435    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type
>   type, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) +249
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.CreateSerializer(Type
>   type) +174
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +84
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonMemberMap.GetSerializer() +373
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.DictionaryRepresentationConvention.Apply(BsonMemberMap
>   memberMap) +22
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions.ConventionRunner.Apply(BsonClassMap
>   classMap) +358
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.AutoMapClass() +79
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbObjectMapper.b__0(BsonClassMap`1
>   classMap) +33
>
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(Action`1
>   classMapInitializer) +64
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbObjectMapper.RegisterModelExtension()
>   +176    Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Pipeline.Initialize.InitializeAnalytics.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +71
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +288
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +396
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +333   [HttpException (0x80004005): ValueFactory attempted
>   to access the Value property of this instance
>
> at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbContactStorage.LoadContactIdentifier(ID
>   id)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.LoadContactIdentifierValue(ID
>   contactId)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.TryLoadContact(ID
>   id, IContactFactory factory,     LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan
>   leaseDuration)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.TryLoadContact(Guid id,
>   LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.TryLoadContact(Guid
>   contactId, Int32 lockDurationMinutes, Boolean exclusive)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)   at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()   12352 18:44:38 ERROR
>   SessionEndPipeline failed. Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunAutomation.RunAutomationX(Database
>   database)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.VisitEndPipeline.Run(VisitEndArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.EndSession.SessionEndPipeline.Run(SessionEndArgs
>   sessionEndArgs)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +124    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +700

**Below from log file**

> 6504 18:43:59 ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   processing/taskAgent Exception: System.TimeoutException Message: A
>   timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =  WritableServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }.  Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "3",
>   ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type   : "Unknown", State :
>   "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 3, EndPoint :
>   "X.X.X.X:27017" }", EndPoint: "X.X.X.X:27017", State: "Disconnected",
>   Type:   "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
>   "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   opening a connection to the server.  --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate
>   using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed:
>   Authentication failed..    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.<AuthenticateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.<AuthenticateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.<AuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }. Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task
>   completedTask)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description,    Task
>   descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector
>   selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteOperation`1
>   operation)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(FindAndModifyArgs args)
>
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2d.<FindAndModify>b__2c()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action
>   action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery
>   query, IMongoSortBy sortBy,     IMongoUpdate update, Boolean
>   returnNew, Boolean upsert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.MongoDbTaskStorageProvider.PickFirstExclusiveTask()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskQueue.TryGetNext(Guid
>   taskIdBoundary, ProcessingTask& workItem)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TasksAgent.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()   8540 18:43:59 ERROR
>   Exception when executing agent aggregation/automationCleanupService
>   Exception: System.TimeoutException Message: A timeout occured after
>   30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   WritableServerSelector,  LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
>   AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster
>   state is { ClusterId : "1",  ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type :
>   "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
>   : 1, EndPoint :  "X.X.X.X:27017" }", EndPoint: "X.X.X.X:27017", State:
>   "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB. 
>   Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a
>   connection to the server. ---> 
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate
>   using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.  --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed:
>   Authentication failed..    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }. Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task
>   completedTask)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description,     Task
>   descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector
>   selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.RemoveFinishedRanges()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.GetOldestUnaggregatedRangeTimestamp()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.RemoveAutomationTransitions(DateTime
>   oldestInclusive, DateTime latestExclusive)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.CleanupAgent.Execute()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()   12352 18:44:38
>   ERROR Cannot create tracker. Exception: System.TimeoutException
>   Message: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, 
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", 
>   ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State :
>   "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : 
>   "X.X.X.X:27017" }", EndPoint: "X.X.X.X:27017", State: "Disconnected",
>   Type: "Unknown",  : "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
>   exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> 
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate
>   using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. ---> 
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed:
>   Authentication failed..    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }. Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task
>   completedTask)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description,    Task
>   descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector
>   selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadOperation`1
>   operation, ReadPreference readPreference)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](FindOneArgs args) 
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2a`1.b__29()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action
>   action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](IMongoQuery
>   query, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbContactStorage.LoadContactIdentifier(ID
>   id)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.LoadContactIdentifierValue(ID
>   contactId)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.TryLoadContact(ID
>   id, IContactFactory factory,     LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan
>   leaseDuration)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.TryLoadContact(Guid id,
>   LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.TryLoadContact(Guid
>   contactId, Int32 lockDurationMinutes, Boolean exclusive)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)   at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()   12352 18:44:38 ERROR
>   SessionEndPipeline failed. Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunAutomation.RunAutomationX(Database
>   database)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.VisitEndPipeline.Run(VisitEndArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.EndSession.SessionEndPipeline.Run(SessionEndArgs
>   sessionEndArgs)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but did you ever fix this problem @andi-ar?